# What factors have led the ANC to continue getting a majority of votes?

Tags: parties, history, south-africa

South Africa is due to have national elections this year. It is possible that the ANC will still get a majority of votes as they have in every other election since independence.

But some have argued that the country is not in a good state. As [the Economist said](https://www.economist.com/the-world-ahead/2023/11/13/south-africa-faces-a-defining-election):

> there is justified disappointment with 30 years of ANC rule. Democracy’s benefits have been fewer than expected, and skewed towards the elites, white and black. When Ipsos, a pollster, asked people from 29 countries in 2023 about the direction of their country, only Argentina and Peru had a higher share saying things were going wrong.

> And little wonder. South Africa’s rates of unemployment, murder and inequality are among the highest in the world. Adjusted for inflation, gdp per person is lower than in 2008. Electricity blackouts are frequent. Anyone who can afford private solutions to public problems pays for them...

> ...At least 80% of South Africans believe that some or all people in government departments, municipalities and the presidency are corrupt, according to Afrobarometer, a pan-African pollster.

The ANC have been in charge for 30 years. They have managed to oust a particularly corrupt president, but the sheer incompetence and corruption has arguably continued. For example, electricity blackouts have only become worse every year and now seriously limit the overall output of the economy. [Some worry](https://www.economist.com/middle-east-and-africa/2023/05/22/business-leaders-fear-that-south-africa-risks-becoming-a-failed-state) that the country is rapidly becoming a failed state.

What factors have allowed them to retain support despite the claims by many about the declining state of the country?

Comment: Voting to close - Your question invites opinion and that is not allowed here as we are a Q&A platform and not a discussion platform - *Is this pessimistic view wrong?* - sorry, we can't predict future events. Please edit and improve your question to meet our minimum guidelines. Thanks.

Comment: Asking 'party x is doing a bad job, why do people vote for them' is asking the wrong question. You need to chose one of the parties, so you should ask whether any of the other parties is expected to do better. If the ANC is doing a lousy job but everyone expects every other party to be even worse than the ANC will still win.

Answer (score 6):

The ANC is the "party of liberation and the party of Black power".  That has allowed it to paint itself as the party to vote for, for Blacks.

[Despite Challenges, South Africa’s ANC Likely to Remain in Power](https://www.cfr.org/blog/despite-challenges-south-africas-anc-likely-remain-power)

> In a country fractured by race in which blacks—about 80 percent of the population—are much poorer than whites—about 9 percent—race is the largest factor in voting behavior. The ANC is now the black political party, despite its multiracial origins. The formal opposition, the Democratic Alliance (DA), is white in origin but is seeking to build multiracial support. The third major party, the Economic Freedom Fighters (EFF), calls for expropriation of white property without compensation. It is entirely a black party. South Africa’s other racial minorities, specifically coloureds `*` (who regard themselves as a separate race, not a mixed race) and those of South and East Asian origin, tend to support the DA or one of the many minor parties.

If there were no white people around, presumably, if the electoral system was clean - it mostly seems to be, then another black party could challenge it.  As it is, "Voting against the ANC" can be painted as "Voting for The (white) Man".

That the ANC doesn't really do all that much good for the population in general really doesn't figure much in all this.  It's a quite stable, self-perpetuating mechanism, until such time as a different party manages to sell itself as equally representative to the Black majority.  The EFF above could easily be worse.

While regrettable, I don't know how unusual this type of system is.  Nor is it necessarily all that based on racism.  Similar cronyism and stagnation has been seen in Algeria, where the stalwarts of the Algerian War remained in power for decades.  Or, *previously*, in Mexico where the [PRI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institutional_Revolutionary_Party) ruled for decades as well:  "we're the guarantors of the liberty of the people!"  I am sure other examples exist.  There's a continuum of clean elections, like South Africa or Mexico, to less clean ones like Algeria, to farcical ones like Maduro's Venezuela.  The end result remains uncompetitive elections, sub-optimal outcomes for the population and rents for the well-connected.

`*` the word `colored` has a different meaning in South Africa from US English and it is how those groups self-describe.